# jQuery API Browser using raw XML from jquery site and XSLT. How to generate and embed runnable code?

Tags: jquery

I have developed a jQuery API browser from the raw XML available from  http://api.jquery.com/api/ they also have a Dynamic API browser which is built from this XML i guess http://api.jquery.com/browser/ but it is slightly difficult to navigate because you do not get to see all the API of one type together, you can only see the details when you click on one of the links. So to overcome this difficulty i have built my own API browser with this raw XML. This is what I have http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/jquery.apitest2.xml. build with XSLT mostly and 4 javascript functions. I did the navigation simplistic and with minimum code and minimum javascript parsing as this XML is big. Left side is menu right side is snapshot of similar APIs and middle is details description. The pages gets loaded only once and hence its fast.

This is what I wanted to share. 
There is a possibility to create dynamically, demo sections. 
 I couldn't figure out how to create sample executable code dynamically from snippets of `<css>, <code> and <html>` dynamically. The codes look so different some methods needs to be called on `$(document).ready()` but some are normal functions which should be outside closures.

I would also like to learn some scalable implementation methods, given that generated HTML is quite big.
I do not want to create many `<iframes/>` which will download lot of files while initial loading.

Comment: The problem you are going to have is with pseudo HTML snippets: it's good that CSS and EmacScript fragments are in CDATA, because they are just unparsed text; but "pseudo" (X)HTML elements can't be in CDATA if you want them to be real HTML elements instead of just unparsed data. It looks like this model only lets you with the disable output escaping mechanism...

Comment: Actually I have the html snippets in `<pre>` tag so it is showing correctly in sccreen as well as in the generated html. Its treated as plain text by XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this although initial loading takes sometime but after that it runs fine. I am creating the HTML for testing based on fixed template each time the user wants to test a scriptlet. The editing that is done is not saved. http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/jquery.apitest2.xml

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the iframes:

as far as I know jQuery doesn't provide some documents that will appear inside the iframes there.

They parse the given code from the example-source and write it into a new document inside the iframes.

Comment: Yes jQuery does provide snippets the trick was to place those script snippets in the body so even if i dont wrap it inside `$(document).ready(...)` it still executes at least once. As for scalable approach i created one textarea to store the template html and generate an iframe as and when required. I am also creating a textarea for editing, in case anyone tries to try out stuff. This is all working in the above url in question.